Cannot find img element with PHP DomDocument
I find a strange problem.
I parse a WordPress post content  via PHP DOMDocument and only print img element, as below:
function myfun($post_id)
{
    //  Get the post conent
    $post = get_post($post_id); 
    $body = $post->post_content;
    
    //  Parse the post content with as UTF-8
    //  Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHtml("<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head><body>".$body."</body></html>");
    
    //  Enumerate the DOM tree
    $doc_root = $doc->documentElement;
    
    enum_dom($doc_root->childNodes, 0);
}

function enum_dom($nodes, $level)
{
    foreach ($nodes AS $item) 
    {
      if (($item->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) && ($item->nodeName == 'img'))
      { 
        print $item->nodeName . PHP_EOL;

        if($item->childNodes || $item->childNodes->lenth > 0) 
        {
          enum_dom($item->childNodes, $level+5);
        }
      }
    }
}


But in this way, the code will NOT output any img elements. However, if I remove the ($item->nodeName == 'img'), then all elements will be printed out, INCLUDE the img element.
Since img is in the DOM, why I cannot filter it with the condition ($item->nodeName == 'img')
Below is the WordPress post content I use for test:
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-43154" title="Excel Invoice Template Site Introduction" src="https://www.sample.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/excel-invoice-template-site-introduction.jpg" alt="Excel Invoice Template Site Introduction" width="600" height="338" />


"img is in the DOM" But not just below the root element, so enum_dom() does nothing.

You may want to use getElementsByTagName().

@Olivier, Your solution is better!

enum_dom($doc_root->childNodes, 0);

The two child nodes of the root element, are head and body. The nodeName of neither of those is img. Therefor, the recursive call
enum_dom($item->childNodes, $level+5);

never happens, because you put that inside the if, that checks if the nodeName of the current element is img.
The recursive call needs to happen regardless of whether the current element is an img or not:
function enum_dom($nodes, $level)
{
    foreach ($nodes AS $item) 
    {
      if (($item->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) && ($item->nodeName == 'img'))
      { 
        print $item->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
      }
      
      if($item->childNodes || $item->childNodes->lenth > 0) 
      {
          enum_dom($item->childNodes, $level+5);
      }
    }
}

(Not sure about the $level+5 part, how that is supposed to make sense. But since you don't seem to be using that variable anywhere, probably doesn't do too much harm either.)
